# Creation of Spring beans without referring or coding in app context file

Tags: spring

I want to know if there is a way to define spring beans which are created without coding them directly in the spring application context file.

Comment: You mean by using annotations like `@Component`?

Comment: Yes its annotation. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use component scan.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

or 
`@ComponentScan({"com.foo.bar", "org.example"})` for java config

That way spring will scan the secified package for classes annotated with `@Component`(or its inheritors `@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Controller`) and will register them as spring beans.

You can read more here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html

Comment: @user2989282 yes, if you don't want to use config file.